# How can i change link with delay after clicking it

Tags: javascript, html

maybe my question is silly and has a very simple answer, but I am new in HTML and javascript and I need your help. Actually is my first website that I'm creating...

Well, my problem is this. I have 2 links on my website

```
<a id="first" href="http://example.com/first-link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-check">First Link</button></a>

<a id="second" href="http://example.com/second-link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-go">Second Link</button></a>
```

Initially, I need to display the first link button, when it's clicked that link button should disappear, a message saying "Checking..." should be displayed for 10 seconds, and then the second link button should appear.

So each of these 3 elements (button 1, message, button 2) should be visible one by one...

I don't know if it helps, but I am using jquery-1.10.2.js on my website.

Can any of you please help me with a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so wouldn't clicking the link take you to that page? unclear how you would wait...

Comment: yes, but the user will come back to my page... this should be something like a link locker

Comment: So show the second link with a timeout, click change the text

Comment: Why there's a button inside of a link tag ?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? This is pure javascript.

```js
first.onclick = (function(){

  first.style.display = "none"
  
  second.style.display = "block"
  
  setTimeout(function(){
  
     second.style.display = "none"
    
     third.style.display = "block"
    
  },5000)
  
})
```

```css
#second, #third {
 display: none
}
```

```html
<a id="first" href="http://example.com/first-link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-check">First Link Click me</button></a>

<span id="second">.... Wait 5s</span>

<a id="third" href="#">YOUR LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just have all elements in the page, and show/hide based on your flow.

```js
$('#first').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#message').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#second').show();
    $('#message').hide();
  }, 10000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="first" href="http://example.com/first-link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-check">First Link</button></a>
<p id="message" style="display:none;">Checking...</p>
<a id="second" style="display:none;" href="http://example.com/second-link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-go">Second Link</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change all 3 buttons with adding a **state class** to the container element.

in the **CSS**:

- show the `#first` link only on empty state (no class)
- show the `loading...` link only on `loading` state
- show the `#third` link only on `ready` state

Then, in the **JavaScript**, all you need to do is add\remove the right class:

```js
first.onclick = (function() {
  container.classList.add('loading');

  return setTimeout(function() {

    container.classList.remove('loading');
    container.classList.add('ready');

  }, 5000);

});
```

```css
.action-container:not(.loading) #second,
.action-container:not(.ready) #third {
  display: none
}

.action-container.loading #first,
.action-container.ready #first {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-container" id="container">
  <a id="first" href="http://example.com/first-link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-check">First Link Click me</button></a>

  <span id="second">.... Wait 5s</span>

  <a id="third" href="#">YOUR LINK</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, this would be also a possible way:

```js
$('#first').on('click', function() {
  // Parent Element of the first button
  var parent = this.parentElement;
  
  // Show message
  $(parent).append('<p>Checking...</p>')
  
  // Remove first button
  $(this).remove();
  
  // Set html content of parent including only the second button (after 1 second)
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(parent).html('<a id="second" href="http://example.com/second-link" target="_blank"><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-go">Second Link</button></a>');
  }, 1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="first" href="#" target=""><button class="btn-icon btn-icon-check">First Link</button></a>
```